# CISCO router 827 - VPN ezvpn configuration

Tags: networking, configuration, vpn, router, cisco

i'm facing with this simple configuration and i can't figure it out.
Scenario:
With a cisco vpn client (or ipad, iphone..) i can connect to my company vpn. 
What i know is:

VPN GROUP NAME

VPN KEY

VPN SERVER PUBLIC IP

VPN USERNAME and PASSWORD

Ip address of virtual adapter created by cisco vpn client: 10.0.201.31 255.255.255.0

My lan 172.23.28.0 255.255.255.224

Company lan 172.19.248.0 255.255.252.0

The question is "How can i handle this for my home's lan with a cisco 827 router ?"

I think the steps are:

1) configuring eth0, dns and dhcp (done)

2) configuring ATM0 and Dialer0 to get internet access (done)

3) configuring access list and ip routes for my lan (done)

4)configuring ezvpn parameters (done)

5) configuring virtual interface with Ip 10.0.201.31 (What kind of interface?)

6) Set inside and outside nat for "crypto ipsec client ezvpn MYVPNTUNNELNAME" (which interfaces and how ?)

7) configuring route to 172.19.248.0 255.255.252.0 (how?)

Here is my configuration:

```
    !
    version 12.3
    no service pad
    service timestamps debug uptime
    service timestamps log uptime
    no service password-encryption
    !
    hostname R827
    !
    boot-start-marker
    boot-end-marker
    !
    enable secret 5 cryptedSecret
    enable password notcrypted
    !
    no aaa new-model
    ip subnet-zero
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.1
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.2
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.3
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.4
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.5
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.6
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.7
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.8
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.9
    ip dhcp excluded-address 172.23.28.10
    !
    ip dhcp pool CeccoDhcp
       network 172.23.28.0 255.255.255.224
       default-router 172.23.28.1
       dns-server 8.8.8.8
    !
    !
    ip name-server 8.8.8.8
    ip name-server 8.8.4.4
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    crypto ipsec client ezvpn MYVPNTUNNELNAME
     connect auto
     group MYGROUPNAME key MYGROUPKEY
     mode network-extension
     peer PUBLICIPOFVPNSERVER
     username MYUSER password  MYPASSWORD
    !
    !
    !
    interface Ethernet0
     ip address 172.23.28.1 255.255.255.224
     ip nat inside
     ip virtual-reassembly
     hold-queue 100 out
    !
    interface ATM0
     no ip address
     no atm ilmi-keepalive
     bundle-enable
     dsl operating-mode auto
     pvc 8/35
      encapsulation aal5mux ppp dialer
      dialer pool-member 1
     !
    !
    interface Dialer0
     ip address negotiated
     ip nat outside
     ip virtual-reassembly
     encapsulation ppp
     ip tcp header-compression
     dialer pool 1
     dialer-group 1
     no cdp enable
     ppp pap sent-username aliceadsl password 7 15130705072F2A203B3F
    !
    ip classless
    ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer0
    ip http server
    no ip http secure-server
    ip nat inside source list 101 interface Dialer0 overload
    !
    !
    access-list 101 permit ip 172.23.28.0 0.0.0.31 any
    dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
    !
    !
    control-plane
    !
    !
    line con 0
     stopbits 1
    line vty 0 4
     password MYTERMINALPASSWORD
     login
    !
    scheduler max-task-time 5000
    end
```

End of configuration.

**Please note:** 
If i add

```
    crypto ipsec client ezvpn MYVPNTUNNELNAME
```

to Dialer0
and

```
    crypto ipsec client ezvpn MYVPNTUNNELNAME inside
```

to Ethernet0
i get this:

```
    Tunnel name : MYVPNTUNNELNAME 
    Inside interface list: Ethernet0,
    Outside interface: Dialer0
    Current State: READY
    Last Event: CONN_UP
```

Hope someone could help me.
Thanks in advance.
Cecco

Comment: You should take this to ServerFault.

Comment: That said, my suggestion is turn on debugging (`debug crypto ezvpn`, `debug crypto isakmp` if I recall correctly) and try to get some additional info as to what's not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved!!

Thanks to James help i switched ezvpn conf to "mode client" and with debug i noticed that the problem was on server side, cause "storage-password enable" was not set.
When company's net admin told me that "storage-password enable" was set i just did:

```
conf t
int Dia0
crypto ipsec client ezvpn MYVPNTUNNELNAME
```

....and everything works perfectly :-)

Comment: If the information provided helped, feel free to upvote my previous answer ("useful").  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I compared your config to some old notes I had. I did work turning up Cisco VPNs in the past so this jogged my memory.

I think the READY state and CONN_UP last event mean that it sits there, prior to authentication. And this may be because you're not telling the 871 how to handle XAUTH.

Try adding the below to your `crypto ipsec client ezvpn` section:

```
xauth userid mode interactive
```

That and turning debugging on should give you something to work on. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: One last thing... when you add the crypto commands under the interfaces, add the inside interface FIRST, and the outside SECOND. I remember that could make a difference in whether it worked or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. my router it's an 827 and this is what i have: R827(config-crypto-ezvpn)#?
Crypto EzVPN configuration commands:
  connect        Connect
  exit           Exit from EzVPN configuration mode
  group          Group Name
  local-address  Interface to use for local address for this ezvpn configuration
  mode           Mode
  no             Negate a command or set its defaults
  peer           Allowed Encryption/Decryption Peer
  username       User Name

Comment: ... so i can't xauth userid mode interactive

Comment: Ok, that's strange. Then maybe you need to look up that specific's IOS version documentation for EasyVPN.
What did the debug output say?

Comment: from debug rows seems connection never happened and router tries to connect for ever

Comment: `16:55:02: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Event: CONN_DOWN
16:55:02: EZVPN(vpnVNS): New State: CONNECT_REQUIRED
16:55:02: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Current State: CONNECT_REQUIRED
16:55:02: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Event: CONNECT
16:55:02: EZVPN(vpnVNS): ezvpn_connect_request
16:55:02: EZVPN(vpnVNS): New State: READY
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Current State: READY
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Event: CONN_UP
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): ezvpn_conn_up CBA71B26 C9C163E5 6C2F4740 9EBAE53A`

Comment: `16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): No state change
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Current State: READY
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Event: XAUTH_REQUEST
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): ezvpn_xauth_request
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): ezvpn_parse_xauth_msg
16:55:04: EZVPN: Attributes sent in xauth request message:
16:55:04:         XAUTH_TYPE_V2(vpnVNS): 0
16:55:04:         XAUTH_USER_NAME_V2(vpnVNS):
16:55:04:         XAUTH_USER_PASSWORD_V2(vpnVNS):
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): send saved username MYUSERNAME and password <omitted>`

Comment: `16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): New State: XAUTH_REQ
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Current State: XAUTH_REQ
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Event: XAUTH_REQ_INFO_READY
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): ezvpn_xauth_reply
16:55:04:         XAUTH_TYPE_V2(vpnVNS): 0
16:55:04:         XAUTH_USER_NAME_V2(vpnVNS): MYUSERNAME`

Comment: `16:55:04:         XAUTH_USER_PASSWORD_V2(vpnVNS): <omitted>
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): New State: XAUTH_REPLIED
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Current State: XAUTH_REPLIED
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Event: XAUTH_STATUS
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): New State: READY
16:55:04: EZVPN(vpnVNS): Current State: READY`

Comment: I don't like the fact that you are using NAT at the same time you are using Easy VPN. Easy VPN handles that on its own and it's not a good idea to do your own NAT.
When your remote network address space is "meaningful" within your network (routable IP address space known to the rest of your network, even if they may be private addresses) then you can use network-extension mode, which has some advantages, mainly your individual remote addresses being reachable from the hub. If you don't (duplicated address space on remote side, for example), then you have to go with client mode.

Comment: See the below, from http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/12_2y/12_2ya4/feature/guide/ftezvpcm.html:

"No Manual NAT/PAT Configuration Allowed
The Cisco Easy VPN Remote feature automatically creates the appropriate NAT/PAT configuration for the VPN tunnel. You therefore must not create a manual NAT/PAT configuration on any interface when using the Cisco Easy VPN Remote feature. If NAT/PAT has already been configured on the router, you must remove that configuration before beginning the Cisco Easy VPN Remote configuration."

Comment: That said, and considering this is your home network, I believe network-extension mode is not the right choice. You should be doing client mode. My suggestion is you remove your current NAT and switch to client mode, and EasyVPN will handle all NAT/PAT for you. After all, when you tested successfully with the VPN software client, that is the mode it uses.